# Quick method to transform a PyTorch tensor with gradient preservation

Tags: pytorch

**Question**:

I need a quick and simple method to transform a PyTorch tensor with dimensions (D, M, M) into a tensor with dimensions (D*4, M//2, M//2) manually without convolutions. I want to use a pooling-like approach but with a flattening and concatenation operation where the kernel size is always 2 and the stride is also 2 to downsample to half. It's essential to keep the gradients.

**Example Input:**

Transform (3, 4, 4) to (12, 2, 2):
***`[[[ 0,  1,  2,  3], [ 4,  5,  6,  7], [ 8,  9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]],`***

***`[[16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23], [24, 25, 26, 27], [28, 29, 30, 31]],`***

***`[[32, 33, 34, 35], [36, 37, 38, 39], [40, 41, 42, 43], [44, 45, 46, 47]]]`***

Desired Output:

***`[[[ 0,  1,  4,  5, 16, 17, 20, 21, 32, 33, 36, 37],`***

***`[ 2,  3,  6,  7, 18, 19, 22, 23, 34, 35, 38, 39]],`***

***`[[ 8,  9, 12, 13, 24, 25, 28, 29, 40, 41, 44, 45],`***

***`[10, 11, 14, 15, 26, 27, 30, 31, 42, 43, 46, 47]]]`***

**Test Code:**

```
# Generate the input tensor
input_tensor = torch.arange(48).reshape(3, 4, 4)

# Get Shape
n, m, _ = input_tensor.shape

# DO CODE operation

#check output output_tensor[:,0,0] == [ 0,  1,  4,  5, 16, 17, 20, 21, 32, 33, 36, 37]
.....
```

My attemp i try to create a middle step in order to get the desired output:

`patches = input_tensor.unfold(1, 2, 2).unfold(2, 2, 2).reshape(n, m//2,m//2, 4)`

**Output:**

```
 output: tensor([[[[ 0,  1,  4,  5], [ 2,  3,  6,  7]],

     [[ 8,  9, 12, 13],
      [10, 11, 14, 15]]],


    [[[16, 17, 20, 21],
      [18, 19, 22, 23]],

     [[24, 25, 28, 29],
      [26, 27, 30, 31]]],


    [[[32, 33, 36, 37],
      [34, 35, 38, 39]],

     [[40, 41, 44, 45],
      [42, 43, 46, 47]]]])
```

but i still need to convert this patches to a vector of 12,2,2 and keep the correct order.

Edit (D*2, M//2, M//2) > (D*4, M//2, M//2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost already did it. After getting to tthe patches with the shape (n, m//2, m//2, 4) you have to flatten the last dimension and permute the tensor to the correct order and `torch.permute` is the way to go here. Here's the complete code:

```
import torch

# Generate the input tensor
input_tensor = torch.arange(48).reshape(3, 4, 4)

# Get Shape
n, m, _ = input_tensor.shape

# Create patches
patches = input_tensor.unfold(1, 2, 2).unfold(2, 2, 2).reshape(n, m//2, m//2, 4)

# Flatten the last dimension and permute the tensor to the correct order
output_tensor = patches.permute(1,2,0,3).reshape(m//2, m//2, n*4)

print(output_tensor)
```

Comment: Thanks very helpful , i was kinda ashamed but hardstuck none the less.

for a batch compatible version :
 # Batch, Depth ,size, size ;
 x = x.unfold(2, 2, 2).unfold(3, 2, 2).reshape(batch, depth, size // 2, size // 2, 4) ;
 x = x.permute(0, 2, 3, 1, 4).reshape(batch, size // 2, size // 2, depth * 4).permute(0, 3, 1, 2) ;
(; - newline)
Please verify before using.