# Quick method to manually expand a PyTorch tensor

Tags: pytorch, torchvision

I need a quick and simple method to transform a PyTorch tensor with dimensions (D, M, M) into a tensor with dimensions (D // 4, M x 2, M x 2) manually without convolutions. I previously arrived to a solution for the  oposite operation.(see comments on the previous question (oposite operation) )

previous question.

[Quick method to transform a PyTorch tensor with gradient preservation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77351856/quick-method-to-transform-a-pytorch-tensor-with-gradient-preservation/77352162#77352162)

```
# Batch, Depth ,size, size -> Batch, 4 x Depth ,size//2, size//2
x = x.unfold(2, 2, 2).unfold(3, 2, 2).reshape(batch, depth, size // 2, size // 2, 4)
x = x.permute(0, 2, 3, 1, 4).reshape(batch, size // 2, size // 2, depth * 4).permute(0, 3, 1, 2)
```

Desired Input:

Transform (12, 2, 2) to (3, 4, 4):

```
[[[ 0,  1,  4,  5, 16, 17, 20, 21, 32, 33, 36, 37],

[ 2,  3,  6,  7, 18, 19, 22, 23, 34, 35, 38, 39]],

[[ 8,  9, 12, 13, 24, 25, 28, 29, 40, 41, 44, 45],

[10, 11, 14, 15, 26, 27, 30, 31, 42, 43, 46, 47]]]
```

Desired Output:

```
[[[ 0,  1,  2,  3], [ 4,  5,  6,  7], [ 8,  9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]],

[[16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23], [24, 25, 26, 27], [28, 29, 30, 31]],

[[32, 33, 34, 35], [36, 37, 38, 39], [40, 41, 42, 43], [44, 45, 46, 47]]]
```

EDIT: preferable working with batch.
test code:

```
import torch
batch = 2
input = torch.arange(3*4*4*batch).reshape(batch,3, 4, 4)
batch, depth, size, _ = input.shape
x = input.unfold(2, 2, 2).unfold(3, 2, 2).reshape(batch, depth, size // 2, size // 2, 4)
x = x.permute(0, 2, 3, 1, 4).reshape(batch, size // 2, size // 2, depth * 4).permute(0, 3, 1, 2)
**reverse operation code**
print((input==x).all())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

```
x.permute(0, 2, 3, 1).reshape(batch, size//2, size//2, depth, 
2,2).permute(0, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5).reshape(batch, depth, size, size)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the unfolding if you chunk along the axis you want to split on. Here's an example that works for your inputs. As a caveat, your first input is size `(2,2,12)`, not `(12,2,2)`, you the dimensions are shuffled.

```py
x = torch.tensor([[[ 0,  1,  4,  5, 16, 17, 20, 21, 32, 33, 36, 37],
[ 2,  3,  6,  7, 18, 19, 22, 23, 34, 35, 38, 39]],
[[ 8,  9, 12, 13, 24, 25, 28, 29, 40, 41, 44, 45],
[10, 11, 14, 15, 26, 27, 30, 31, 42, 43, 46, 47]]])

y = torch.tensor([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3], [ 4,  5,  6,  7], [ 8,  9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]],
[[16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23], [24, 25, 26, 27], [28, 29, 30, 31]],
[[32, 33, 34, 35], [36, 37, 38, 39], [40, 41, 42, 43], [44, 45, 46, 47]]])

x_permuted = torch.stack(x.split(2, dim=-1)).reshape(3,2,2,4).permute(0,2,1,3).reshape(3,4,4)

(y==x_permuted).all()
>True
```

Comment: i tried validating with a diferent input but the output doesnt match:

import torch

batch = 2
input = torch.arange(3*4*4*batch).reshape(batch,3, 4, 4)
batch, depth, size, _ = input.shape
x = input.unfold(2, 2, 2).unfold(3, 2, 2).reshape(batch, depth, size // 2, size // 2, 4)
x = x.permute(0, 2, 3, 1, 4).reshape(batch, size // 2, size // 2, depth * 4).permute(0, 3, 1, 2)
test = x[0]
#test[:,0,0] = tensor([ 0,  1,  4,  5, 16, 17, 20, 21, 32, 33, 36, 37])
x_permuted = torch.stack(test .split(2, dim=-1)).reshape(3,2,2,4).permute(0,2,1,3).reshape(3,4,4)
#(input[0]==x_permuted).all()